# Old property value passed to observer in polymer?

Tags: polymer

I observe properties for changes in polymer:

```
properties: {
  foo: Object,
  bar: Object,
},
observers: [
  "fooChanged(foo, bar),"
],

fooChanged: function() {
  // Do work.
},
```

However, within the `fooChanged` method, `this.foo` and `this.bar` often take on their previous values (before they changed).

Does polymer not guarantee that properties are updated within observer methods?

Comment: You should read the new values from the observer's function arguments, which are guaranteed to be new (i.e., `fooChanged: function(newFoo, newBar)`). Can you provide an example, where `this.foo` sometimes takes on the previous value?

Answer (score 0):

An observer fires *in response* to an [observable change](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes) on the specified path. So, when the observer fires, the path that changed will have its new value, not the old value.

The order of property effects as described in the [documentation 
on the Polymer data system](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-system#property-effects) is:

1. Computed properties.
2. Data bindings.
3. Reflected values.
4. Observers.
5. Change notification events.

Someone asked about this recently at work (I am a Polymer tech writer) but I haven't been able to reproduce it. At the time of writing I haven't seen any code samples of a property having the old value when the observer fires. (I would be interested if anyone reading this now has had this issue and can help me out by giving a code sample.)